# bootstrap-vue - table won't get updated after AJAX request (vue2.js)

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2

I'm pretty new with vue.js and I saw this great library that doing exactly what I need for my project: [Boostrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.github.io/docs/components/tables)

[example source code](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/master/docs/pages/docs/components/tables.vue)

I followed the basic instructions and I've added an small change, ajax call for dynamic content:

```
<layout :docs="docs">
    <template slot="demo">

        <b-table
                stripped
                hover
                :items="items"
                :fields="fields"
                :current-page="currentPage"
                :per-page="perPage"
                :filter="filter"
        >
            <template slot="name" scope="item">
                {{item.value.first}} {{item.value.last}}
            </template>

        </b-table>

    </template>

</layout>
```

export default {

```
    mounted () {
       this.get_data();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            docs: {
                component: 'bTable'
            },
            items: [],
            fields: {
                name: {label: 'Person Full name', sortable: true},
            },
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 5,
            filter: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        get_data () {            
        this.$http.get("myapp/users").then(res => {
            if (res.body) {
                this.items = res.body;
            } else {
                this.error = true;
            }
        });
      }
    }
};
```

So the problem is -  after I'm getting the Ajax response and the "items" variable initialized with the data but the table still won't get update.

The strangest part is that with static data its works fine (as shown in the example source code, without AJAX).

Any idea why? 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it seems that it necessary to define the following fields according to the value I received in the response:

```
fields: {
            name: {label: 'Person Full name', sortable: true},
        }
```

so if my json looks like this:

```
{user_name: "user"}
```

it should look like this:

```
fields: {
            user_name: {label: 'Person Full name', sortable: true},
        }
```

Anyway, [Yoram de Langen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696731/yoram-de-langen) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug the `res.body` and what it contains? What is the structure your `myapp/users` returns? Do you return the structure directly like so:

```
[
    { "name": "item 1"},
    { "name": "item 1"},
]
```

or does it look like this:

```
{
    "result": [
        { "name": "item 1"},
        { "name": "item 1"},
    ]

}
```

In case of the latest one your `this.items = res.body` should be: `this.items = res.body.result`